# Cleaning up & filling in categorical variables for Data Science analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I'm taking on my very first machine learning problem, and I'm struggling with cleaning my categorical features in my dataset. My goal is to build a rock climbing recommendation system.

**PROBLEM 1:**

I have three columns related columns that have erroneous information:

What it looks like now:
[image: Example Table]

What I want it to look like:
[image: Would like my table to look like this...]

If you groupby the location name, there are different location_id numbers and countries associated with that one name. However, there is a clear winner/clear majority to each of these discrepancies. I have a data set of 2 million entries and the mode of the location_id & location_country GIVEN the location_name is overwhelming pointing to one answer (example: "300" & "USA" for clear_creek).

Using pandas/python, how do I group my dataset by the location_name, compute the mode of location_id & location_country based on that location name, and then replace the entire id & country columns with these mode calculations based on location_name to clean up my data?

I've played around with groupby, replace, duplicated, but I think ultimately I will need to create a function that will do this, and I honestly have no idea where to start. (I apologize in advance for my coding naivety)I know there's got to be a solution, I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

**PROBLEM 2:**

Also, any one have suggestions on filling in NaN values in my location_name category (42,012/2 million) and location_country(46,890/2 million) columns? Is it best to keep as an unknown value? I feel like filling in these features based on frequency would be a horrible bias to my data set.

```
data = {'index': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
        'location_name': ['kalaymous', 'kalaymous', 'kalaymous', 'kalaymous',
                          'clear_creek', 'clear_creek', 'clear_creek', 
                          'clear_creek', 'clear_creek'],
        'location_id': [100,100,0,100,300,625,300,300,300], 
        'location_country': ['GRC', 'GRC', 'ESP', 'GRC', 'USA', 'IRE', 
                             'USA', 'USA', 'USA']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

***looking for it to return:

```
improved_data = {'index': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
            'location_name': ['kalaymous', 'kalaymous', 'kalaymous', 'kalaymous',
                              'clear_creek', 'clear_creek', 'clear_creek', 
                              'clear_creek', 'clear_creek'],
            'location_id': [100,100,100,100,300,300,300,300,300], 
            'location_country': ['GRC', 'GRC', 'GRC', 'GRC', 'USA', 'USA', 
                                 'USA', 'USA', 'USA']}

new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(improved_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `transform` by calculating mode using [`df.iat[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html):

```
df=(df[['location_name']].join(df.groupby('location_name').transform(lambda x: x.mode()
                                                   .iat[0])).reindex(df.columns,axis=1))
print(df)
```

---

```
  index location_name location_id location_country
0     1     kalaymous         100              GRC
1     1     kalaymous         100              GRC
2     1     kalaymous         100              GRC
3     1     kalaymous         100              GRC
4     5   clear_creek         300              USA
5     5   clear_creek         300              USA
6     5   clear_creek         300              USA
7     5   clear_creek         300              USA
8     5   clear_creek         300              USA
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) in combination with [`pd.Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) and cast that back to your dataframe with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
m1 = df.groupby('location_name')['location_id'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
m2 = df.groupby('location_name')['location_country'].agg(pd.Series.mode)

df['location_id'] = df['location_name'].map(m1)
df['location_country'] = df['location_name'].map(m2)
```

---

```
print(df)
   index location_name  location_id location_country
0      1     kalaymous          100              GRC
1      2     kalaymous          100              GRC
2      3     kalaymous          100              GRC
3      4     kalaymous          100              GRC
4      5   clear_creek          300              USA
5      6   clear_creek          300              USA
6      7   clear_creek          300              USA
7      8   clear_creek          300              USA
8      9   clear_creek          300              USA
```

Comment: This is great! This worked. 2 questions: Would there be a way to ignore NaN values in the "location_name" column while doing this because it spread my NaN values to all the columns? Also, would it be possible for me to use this same code to then clear up the "location_name" column BASED on the "location_id" or "country"? I was thinking since the other two columns would be cleaned up, it may help me to groupby those to help clean up the original "location_name".

Comment: Not sure what you mean, since groupby ignores `NaN`, could maybe explain more in your question, or even better update your example dataframe? For the second part, you can definitely use it to clean up `location_name`: `m3 = df.groupby('location_id')['location_name'].agg(pd.Series.mode)`. After that do `df['location_name'] = df['location_id'].map(m3)`

Comment: hmmmm i didnt know goupby ignored NaN values... so excuse the awful context knowledge, but why would my null count change across all three columns? Before running the code **location_id**   = 0 NaNs , **location_name** = 42012 NaNs, **location_country** = 40,620 NaNs ... After running the code, all three categories had 42,012 NaNs. If the NaNs are ignored by groupby, I'm not sure how this happened? Thank you so much for ALL your help this fine Saturday!

Comment: Ok this should help clarify... Here are some of the NaN entries before: NaN_data_before = {'location_name': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN',
                              'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 
                              'NaN'],
            'location_id': [31956,31956, 0,31956,0,684,163,22703], 
            'location_country': ['GBR', 'GBR', 'NaN', 'GBR', 'NaN', 'FRA', 
                                 'SWE', 'SWE']}

Comment: Here are the NaN entries after:                                                                 
      NaN_data_after = {'location_name': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN',
                              'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 
                              'NaN'],
            'location_id': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN',
                              'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 
                              'NaN'], 
            'location_country': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN',
                              'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 
                              'NaN']}

Answer (score 0):

As Erfan mentions it would be helpful to have a view on your expected output for the first question.

For the second pandas has a [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method. You can use this method to fill the NaN values. For example to fill values with 'UNKNOWN_LOCATION' you could do the following:

```
df.fillna('UNKNOWN_LOCATION')
```

See potential solution for first question:

```
df.groupby('location_name')[['location_id', 'location_country']].apply(lambda x: x.mode())
```

Comment: Thank you! I will use this for the second question.